# Dollar for dollar: hyphens?

Tags: hyphenation

Given the two following phrases:

> Dollar for dollar, all donations will be matched this holiday.

and

> Private donors are offering a dollar-for-dollar match for your holiday gift.

Is that hyphenation correct? I'm going from my gut; what's the rule here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are correct in both instances.**

In your first example "Dollar for dollar" is a phrase. No issues there.

In you second example, you're using the phrase "dollar for dollar" as an adjective. In this case, you have what's appropriately called a "phrasal adjective". (Or sometimes a "hyphenated adjective" or even a "hyphenated phrasal adjective".)

> When a phrasal adjective precedes a noun, it usually takes a hyphen or, for phrases of three or more words, hyphens. This makes things easier for your reader and helps prevent miscues.

([Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/grammar/phrasal-adjectives/))

So yes, when you use a phrase as an adjective, your phrase-as-an-adjective usage should be hyphenated.